# removing duplicates in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string like the one given below.

```
String1 = "a,b,,,c"
```

I want to replace the commas occuring in the middle with a single comma i.e. remove duplicate values.How would I do it.

Comment: I was able to remove the duplicates at the end of the String using the follwoing expression.str = str.replace(/,+$/, ",");
How do i do it in the middle of the String?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/[,]{2,}/g, ',')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnQt4/

Comment: I have a doubt.what does {2,} do in the above expression?

Comment: @sathishkumar it means `match it 2 or more times`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
String1.replace(/,+/g, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string1="a,b,,,c";
repl = string1.replace(/,{2}/g, '');
//=> a,b,c
```

OR using lookahead:

```
repl = string1.replace(/,(?=,)/g, '');
//=> a,b,c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something fairly generic that would work for any repeated string: `/(.)(?=\1)/g`

If you only want commas, simply use `/,(?=,)/g`

Replace the result with an empty string.

`string1 = string1.replace(/,(?=,)/g, '');`

Demo:
http://regex101.com/r/zA0kQ4